# My IOS App has been rejected- Data Storage Guidelines (2.23) I have 2 possible suspects

Tags: ios, objective-c, appstore-approval

my app has been rejected due to iCloud Storage Restrictions. (2.23). 
There are lots of questions for this situation, but i am still not sure why my app has been rejected.. Here are my suspects:

1- My app downloads pdf files and images for letting users see on  "offline" mode when a user selects a row from a tableview. I've set my download folder as "Documents/privateDownloads" and set the folder (and files inside) url flags as "do not backup"

2- My app also has a 2Mb. "preload.json" file, which my app reads the file at first launch and preloads into the database only at first launch (with a progress hud showing the progress of importing data). I haven't set the "preload.json" file as "do not backup".I just drag dropped the file into "Supporting Files" group in Xcode.

My guess is the problem lies in the 2nd suspect, but i've also read that i should move the "privateDownloads" folder into "Application Support" Folder instead of Documents folder.

i always stored my offline files on nsurl cache for a very long time (technically forever), but this time i've decided to do like this.

thanks for reading and helping.

Edit: there is a note from app store for rejection reason:

> "In particular, we found that on launch and/or content download, your
>   app stores 3.6MB"

When i control this issue, this is happening after my application "preloads" the data. But what i really don't get it is, i am storing this preloaded data in core data. So yes, i want this data to be backed up in iCloud?!

Comment: best way to debug is go to settings app and check the storage your app is taking for iCloud, if for each download of pdf -> it is increasing then that will be the issue. if it does not increase solve the 2nd suspect

Comment: Thanks, i was thinking about how to test this.

Comment: i have tested and it doesn't seem to be increasing... :/ i've also requested a technical support from apple...

Comment: @Kabira i have given new informations about the problem, can you please check again..

Comment: do you want the data to sync ?, basically you know how to solve it. If you dont want to solve.. write a appeal to the review team with your comments why the data should sync.

Comment: the preloading process takes a long time, it is a text file with 2mb size.. i guess the best way is to wait for apple tech support guys..

Comment: How did you resolve it?

Comment: @CharlieS The problem was too tricky. The main reason that rejected my app was i was populating core data from a local data file (it was in the bundle). And apple guys told me that, i shouldn't use the same data again and send it to iCloud. So i put a repopulated sqlite file in my app instead of populating dataset from the local file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue of your seed data being too large, you might split your Core Data stack in two separate stores - one which stores the user data and is backed up to iCloud. And a second one which stores the seeded data imported from your JSON. This store could then be excluded from iCloud backup via the "do not backup"-flags.

Another recommended way would be to ship a pre-populated store like described in [this article on objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/importing-large-data-sets-into-core-data.html). Since you mentioned your preload.json is several MB, this would be even more desirable to pre-generate the store once than on every device on initial app startup. And you could apply the required file attributes for not backing it up more easily.

Comment: You could just try resubmitting, btw - I've never seen them so aggressive about the backup limits.

Comment: @Mathhias sadly,  this is the second time my app has been rejected. i have changed my app to set "do not backup" for downloaded items and resubmitted, but i see that this is not the case, i will try to preload data as mentioned the article.. Looks like they are starting to get more aggressive over backup limits :/

Comment: lookh like i have solved the issue by bundling a preloaded sqlite file and copying the file into the application support/db folder. since i designed the sqlite file to be regeneratable, i also added do not backup attribute to the db folder.

Answer (score 1):

The issue won't have anything to do with your preload.json file. If that's included in your app distribution, it is part of the app and you don't need to do anything different with it.

I would suspect that the reviewer didn't notice you were setting the 'do not backup' flag on files you've added to the Documents/privateDownloads folder, or that you have a bug and the flag isn't being set at all. It is safer, if you're able, to store those kinds of files in a /Library/Caches sub directory. Then you don't need to worry about the flag.

Comment: i have tested that the attribute has been added to the files by running "xattr" command and i am getting "com.apple.metadata:com_apple_backup_excludeItem". but i think i am gonna move all those files into Caches directory just to be sure.

Comment: i have added more information about the problem. i am starting to thinking about the preloading is the main issue.. can you please check my edit on my question?

Comment: Hmm, if the data you're preloading never changes than @Matthias' idea to use two stores is a good one. If it's just the initial starting point for the user and that data changes (to user content, not just more stuff downloaded from your server or something), then you may want to stick with what you're doing and appeal to the review board about the rejecting. Explain why the data needs to be backed up etc, that it can't just be recreated if lost.